# ReplaySubject.First() blocks unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, system.reactive

I am encountering an absolutely bizarre behaviour in a Silverlight application on which I am working. Please see the following code:

```
var replaySubject = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
    replaySubject.OnNext("This can never block... surely?");

var s = replaySubject.First();
Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

Basically, my app comes through this piece of code repeated and it always prints out the message... except for in one particular scenario in which the thread blocks on the `First()` line.

It's always on the UI thread. If I set a break point on the line with `First()`, and drill into the `replaySubject` with the debugger, I can see the string in its queue.

Can anyone think of any scenario that would cause the `First()` call to block here?

BTW: It's RX version 1.1.11111

Comment: @Picrofo EGY - Thanks for putting the code keywords into code blocks for me. 

However, I'm not sure why you should correct "I am" into "I'm" - is there some policy on use of contractions? 

Also, I am English and so behaviour is spelt with a "U" here. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: No problems at all! There's no policy for word spelling, I just wanted to make the question more formal. I hope I did not cause you any  inconvenience. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so it turns out that by default, `ReplaySubject` uses the `Scheduler.CurrentThread`.

If I explicitly set the `ReplaySubject` to use `Scheduler.Immediate` or `Scheduler.ThreadPool`, then it works as expected.

```
var replaySubject = new ReplaySubject<string>(1, Scheduler.Immediate);
    replaySubject.OnNext("This can never block... surely?");

var s = replaySubject.First();
Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

I still need to investigate how it is that the UI thread gets itself into this mess in my particular scenario but for now, this solves the issue.

--- edited ---

OK, on further investigation, it turns out that the above piece of code for most of the time is initiated on a ThreadPool thread. Even though, when it reaches the code, it is on the Dispatcher thread, Scheduler.CurrentThread puts the ReplaySubject back onto the original ThreadPool thread.

However, in the scenario where it is breaking, everything starts with the user clicking a button. This is obviously on the UI thread, and when it reaches this piece of code, Scheduler.CurrentThread is now the UI thread, and since we are already on the UI thread, we have a deadlock. First is waiting for the ReplaySubject to pump - but the pump is queued up behind the current action. Subtle and something of which to be aware.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems there are no subscribers registered on this `Observable`. So it may wait for one to subscribe so it can give you the first one available.

You might try `FirstOrDefault` instead to see if it is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the response René. AFAIK First() sets up a subscription, takes 1 and then closes the subscription. Also, if what you said was true, then the above code would always block - rather than what I'm seeing which is that it works repeatedly, and then suddenly blocks.